# Add array of items in object in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I started playing with MongoDB recently and I created a small database for learning purposes.

I used this to get an array with items

```
> var myitems = db.items.find({ $or: [ {"title": "item 1"}, {"title": "item 2"}, {"title": "item 3"}] })
> myitems
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570a841a8b71efa49d08fdda"), "title" : "item 1", "date" : ISODate("2016-04-10T16:49:30.242Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570a850c8b71efa49d08fddb"), "title" : "item 2", "date" : ISODate("2016-04-10T16:53:32.554Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570a85128b71efa49d08fddc"), "title" : "item 3", "date" : ISODate("2016-04-10T16:53:38.554Z") }
```

I also have a list object

```
{
    "_id": int,
    "total_items": int,
    "items": [
        "item_id": int
    ]
}
```

I want to insert my `items` array into `list` collection entries. Something like this:

```
> db.lists.insert({ "total_items": 5, "items": { $addToSet: myitems} })
```

Of course it didn't work. And that's what I'm looking for. A way to get the IDs from my `items` list and use them to insert a new entry to `lists`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user3100115 What part of my question makes it hard for you to understand? No irony here, I'm just trying to find the obfuscated parts to fix them :)

Comment: You said *I want to insert my items array into lists* I don't know the list you are talking about, also I failed to see the expected output. Also is there any relation between the `items` and the  `lists` collection?

Comment: @user3100115 The `lists` collections has an array with `items`. That's the connection between them. When I'm saying * I want to insert my items array into lists* I mean I want to insert `items` into new entries for the `list` collection. The expected output is a list entry like this: `{"_id" : 38126389, "total_items": 5, "items": [ "item_id": 76534, "item_id": 243234, "item_id": 321978]}`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `insert` command when you should be using the `update` command.

```
db.lists.updateOne({
    _id: "abc"
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        items: episodes
        }
})
```

Full docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Comment: The `lists` table is empty. Can I use the update command on an empty list? Or you're saying I should use the `insert` to add a dummy list entry and then the `update` to configure it?

Comment: No, you don't need to create the field first, it'll create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well I just tried it. It's not working I get an exception.`016-04-10T23:08:16.545+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] warning: log line attempted (14kB) over max size (10kB), printing beginning and end ... uncaught exception: WriteError({`